# Which solution i can use for guaranteed notifications (it is not about push notification)?

Tags: android, ios, mobile, notifications

I have server and if something change on server i wanna that all mobile app will get notification about. I am going to send many messages per day (around 200)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You should take a look at this:

https://developer.android.com/google/gcm/index.html

Regards

Comment: not only for android apps! I just need that notificaition server will send to mobile app message and app will update data from server it is that i need!))

Comment: Is your app hybrid? I mean, is developed in each native languaje for each OS, or developed with html and packed?

Comment: second one is more correct i am going to use PhoneGap

Comment: Well then you have to take a look at these plugins, 
https://github.com/phonegap-build/PushPlugin
https://github.com/Pushwoosh/phonegap-cordova-push-notifications